# Gnome/msitools build failure with "No package 'libgsf-1' found" error

Tags: gcc, windows-installer, centos7, gnome, msitools

I have cloned "https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/msitools/-/tree/v0.100" in my Centos7 host and trying to build, but facing following error and even though required package is already installed, it still doesn't work.

Below is the error I am getting when tried to build the code using the "autogen.sh" in the code base.

**Error:**

```
Checking for GSF... no configure: error: Package requirements (libgsf-1) were not met: No package 'libgsf-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GSF_CFLAGS
and GSF_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

But the issue is I have the **libgsf** rpm already installed

```
[meuser@localhost msitools]$ rpm -qa | grep libgsf
libgsf-1.14.26-7.el7.x86_64
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building software on top of another package, you should install the *development* package, which will contain the necessary stuff like include headers, pkg-config files (which it's looking for here) and others.

CentOS/Fedora in general denote development packages by adding a "-devel" suffix, which is also the case here. So the package you're looking for is `libgsf-devel`